# Best way to Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I currently have my Online Store as a Sub-Domain of my main site and my host is having all sorts of trouble getting the "wildcard" ssl certificate to work with the redirects and the CDN.

I am considering just moving the store to a sub-directory of the main site to rid us of the wildcard ssl.

My concern is that the Search Engines have the Store indexed as https://store.xxxxxxxx.com. When the wildcard ssl is gone and the sub-domain is no longer https how do I go about redirecting from the Sub-Domain to the new Sub-Directory.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Redirect` in your `.htaccess` to redirect the user. This will require you to keep the subdomain operational.

```
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/store/
```

The `301` is a permanent redirect. Search engines are usually smart enough to index this result permanently.

I recommend you also notify the search engines with your changes to speed up the process. This process is different for each search engine.

Comment: Maybe I should add this to the question, maybe someone here can help solve the problem. I am using 1and1 and the CDN Plus via CloudFlare. Right now I am bypassing the CDN and the redirects are working fine with                                                                                     RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]                                                                                         any ideas if this code should work with CloudFlare or what change to that redirect code would get it to work?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, when I hit enter on the keyboard it submits the comment as opposed to creating a line break.